# Burning rubber smell from Ford F-250 -- diagnosis?

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, smell

I have a 2006 Ford F-250 Super Duty, gasoline V8 5.4L, automatic transmission, rear-wheel-drive.  When driving on the highway, a burning rubber smell developed.  I got the truck home, then to the shop, as soon as practical.

Prior to this burning rubber smell, there had been some noticeable issues with steering, reminiscent of a problem with tie-rod ends.  The repair shop thought these two issues were related, and they determined that there was a problem with the wheel bearings and the grease surrounding them.  The deficiency in grease, they thought, was causing the burning rubber smell and the steering issues.

After their repair, the steering issues are much better.  However, the burning rubber smell remains, and it seems to be coming more from the engine compartment anyway.  The belt appears to be fine -- no noticeable wear and tear, etc.  What else could the problem be?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few different rubber hoses in the average engine bay - have you check to make sure none are in contact with anything hot? Especially any that run near to the exhaust manifold.

For that matter, if you can get under it, check the entire exhaust to make sure nothing is in contact with it that shouldn't be. You've mentioned the belt which would have been my next suspect - I presume you've also checked any extra ancillary belts?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Nick said, burnt oil also creates the burnt rubber smell.  Check if there's an oil leak that could be hitting hot exhaust parts.